# How to remove elements of a list of lists that occur in another list

Tags: python

I am an absolute newbie in Python.  I have two lists, `aa` and `bb`:

```
aa = [[-10, 6], [-8, 1], [-7, 8], [-5, 3], [-4, 10], [-3, -2], [-2, 5], [0, 0], [1, 7], [3, 2]]
bb = [[-5, 3], [-2, 5], [3, 2], [5, -3], [2, -5], [-3, -2]]
```

I need to make another list which will have the same format as `aa` and `bb`, but will hold `aa[i,j]` added to every point in `bb`, i.e., 10×6 new points.  Many will be redundant and I removed them with `numpy.unique`.  Now I want to remove from `aa`, all the points in `bb`.  How to do this pythonically?  Also, any comment on the first part of the code. Now how to remove `bb` from `cc`?

```
cc=[]
cc.append([])
cc.append([])

for a in aa:
    for b in bb:
        cc[0].append(a[0]+b[0])
        cc[1].append(a[1]+b[1])

dd=np.unique(np.transpose(cc),axis=0)
```

Comment: This question has nothing to do with tuples...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on how to provide a [minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`list comprehension`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). The code is following:

```
>>> print([item for item in aa if item not in bb])
[[-10, 6], [-8, 1], [-7, 8], [-4, 10], [0, 0], [1, 7]]
```

Comment: Thank very much.  It works and I understand it... nice.

Comment: @RobJarvis, I am glad I could help. If the answer is correct, please, consider to accept it and vote on it. More info about, what to do, when someone answers your question, can be found [on this page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

For making another array cc with the same format first convert your lists to bumpy arrays and do addition using list comprehension

```
import numpy as np
cc = [list(a + b) for a in np.array(aa) for b in np.array(bb)]
```

To remove from aa all points in bb

```
result=[a for a in aa if(ele not in bb)]
```